# Good open source or good community edition ETL tool

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, etl

I was working previously on No-Sql like MongoDB. Now I want to switch to ETL process, for that I was searching ETL tools which integrate to MongoDB, Hadoop and that tool should be having good community edition or open source because of initially I want to learn ETL so currently not possible to buy the Enterprise Edition, so any one knows which one is good ETL tool which satisfied my requirement.

Comment: Check out Pentaho Suite, specifically the Kettle software.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best is definitely [Talend Open Studio for Big Data](http://www.talend.com/products/big-data). But it requires a lot of hacking for effective work (you may need to implement your own components or inject custom Java-code to get the desired result).

Answer (score 0):

I think Kettle is one of the most popular (at least from what I have noticed). 
[Kettle](http://kettle.pentaho.com/)

It has a lot of features and is "fairly" user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [StreamSets Data Collector](https://streamsets.com/opensource). It has a modern web based interface and a growing community. It's Apache 2.0 licensed. Supports much of the Hadoop ecosystem and mongodb out of the box.

Full disclosure: I'm a committer on this project.